# Good writing software for tracking information/facts (for Man vs Nature plot)

Tags: fiction, software, resources, research, organization

I have been looking for a writing software, but while I have seen a number of mentions about how this or that program helps you keep track of characters, I haven't seen any mentions of ones that are good at helping you keep track of information.

I am writing a Man vs. Nature story. There are only a few characters other than the protagonist, and they don't take much time on stage. What I need to keep track of is **data** - what food is available, how much of certain limited resources he has used, tracking his travel, that sort of thing. Are there any writing programs that would help with this?

If there are no writing programs that would do this, are there any other (non-writing) programs that could help me track this kind of information? Or even any techniques that would work well? I'm almost at the tearing-my-hair stage on this.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are looking for, but scrivener works really well for me for a lot of things. You can even make hyperlinks to certain other pages, to navigate quickly.

Comment: Related, might be useful, not a dupe: Timeline software: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/is-there-any-good-time-line-software-out-there/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than Scrivener, already noted above, Excel or another spreadsheet program might be what you need here. In your first column you have your scene or other outline notation to identify where your character is in the story, and then your subsequent columns are *Food Remaining* or *Location* or whatever. If you want to get real fancy-schmancy, you can even use the columns to plot a nifty line chart to show diminishing stores.

Answer (score 1):

[yWriter](http://www.spacejock.com/yWriter5.html) also keeps a timeline for each viewpoint character and keeps track of characters, locations, and objects present on a scene-by-scene basis.